# I accidentally deleted a vertex

Tags: edit-mode

So I'm relatively new to blender, and I've been following a tutorial to get started. I'm at a part of the tutorial creating a mug, but I accidentally deleted one vertex on the lip on the mug:[image] (which, oddly enough, can be seen in edit mode but there is no hole in object mode:)[image] and didn't realise 'til later, so I can't simply undo back to before I deleted it. I have no clue how to put it back. help?

Comment: THIS is a job for "F2" Mesh Tools. It's an addon you can enable (Edit > Preferences) and it will correctly place a vertex in EXACTLY a situation like this. With F2 addon enabled, in Edit Mode for your mug [Tab] select the vertex that IS already in the corner opposite of your missing vertex. Press [F] then commit to that new vertex with a left-click (I think). Now, two vertices selected and [F] will produce a FACE. Make enough Faces to close the hole the right way. But creating that dangling vertex is really F2's power.

Comment: thank you for your help! However, after I closed and reopened the file... the hole mysteriously vanished. I guess it got fixed automatically lol? thanks anyway though!

Comment: When anything in Ediit mode is missing but is shown in Object mode it is not deleted of course since Object mode shows the data is there; that vertex was hidden with shortcut H. To unhide press Alt+H in Edit mode. I can't tell how it appeared back after reopening since hiding like any operation is saved with file

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

- Enable the *Type of Element to Snap to* > *Vertex*. You won't need to enable the *Snap* button, you can use the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> to activate snapping when working.
- Select the vertices on the top, extrude it on the Z axis, use the snap so that the extrude reaches the top ring level.
- Fill the faces.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

.. Loads of ways to do it.. but one option..

Assuming your mug is circular, Z-up..

Set Pivot to '3D Cursor' and Snap to 'Active', 'Vertex', affecting rotation

[image]

- Select a good circle in your mug, which will yield its XY center
- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > 'Cursor To Selected'

[image]

- Select a region of faces you can copy to patch the hole
- In Vertex Mode, select a suitable vertex to snap to, and make it active

[image]

- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd><kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> duplicate and rotate the patch, and snap it into place.

[image]

After <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> merge > 'By Proximity'.. repair done.

Comment: Note that if it was deleted it wouldn't be shown in Object mode as clear surface rather the same as in Edit mode instead. But in case if vertex was deleted F2 would be probably the fastest way (lots of ways though indeed)

Comment: @MrZak Point 1: with you..that would explain the mysterious reappearance....Point 2; I still haven't got the F2 way.. restoring the missing vertex n the right place? I'll have to keep trying.. I just wanted to guarantee the curvature... (I use F2 all the time, just not this way)

Comment: or even simpler, select the 2 vertices and extrude up on the Z axis, with the snap enabled so that they stick to the right level, then fill the holes

Comment: @moonboots exactly.. so long as the framework is there, somewhere, to capture the curve. I guess I was thinking worst-case. Which this isn't. :)

Comment: sure your method is good in some cases  ;)

Comment: @Robin F2 way is [simple, select corner vertex and hover mouse over empty space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41ExY.gif) where you want face to be, then some cleanup to fill in last face and top ones.

Comment: @MrZak  Why, Thank you! There's a knack to it. I especially like the Alt-J at the end :). It may be obvious to you.. but maybe that gif  should  be in an answer?

Comment: @Robin you can append it to your answer as one more method. Though the question from beginning was about something else likely however OP "automatically" fixed it so no one knows exactly now